# Does 3-check help you in any way for normal chess?

Tags: chess-variants, check

Does a variant called 3-check, where you have to check the opponent 3 times to win, actually improve your train of thought and analysis of normal chess, or is it close enough to normal chess to actually help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me yes, 3-check does help you improve your normal chess to some extent.

Here's why:

- You need to look for some long variations to see and prevent any further checks by the opponents.
- Second is that you learn about king safety which is very important in normal chess. You learn not to expose your king in the game.
- You learn some specific variations which might help you in gaining an advantage over your opponent in the opening. This is again similar to the normal variant of chess.
- In order, to defeat your opponent you need to give 3 checks. To do that, you need to develop your pieces. This way, you learn to develop your pieces.
- Plus, you need to defend very tightly if your king is open. This improves the defending skills of a player.

But playing a lot of 3-checks is usually not good for normal chess. *By playing a lot*, I mean you are not giving time to normal chess.

- Normal variant requires studying endgames which is usually not seen in the 3-checks variant.
- Normal chess requires studying/analyzing a lot of variations with the help of engines.
- Normal chess usually doesn't end *quickly* if I talk about some high-level games.

The main reason why it probably improves your normal chess is that it's format is similar to that of normal chess unlike other variants like atomic.